# javascript (document.getelementbyid) in an echo not working (probably wrong usage of quotes)

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

i'm running an while (php) which builds rows while onclick they open modals. but i'm not able to get te javascript properly in the echo.

i've read a lot on the internet but none of them are using that much quotes as me.

bit more detail then before. there's a database which is called "nuujts" and contains an 'id', 'titel', 'subtitel', 'inhoud'(content), 'aafbeelding'(html img src=on server)

underneight is a example of a hardcoded version which now needs to be extracted from the mysql server

document.getElementByID should be $row['id']

```
<li onclick="document.getElementById('2').style.display='block'" class="w3-border">
   <a href="#">
      <div class="w3-row">
         <img src="images/tumbnail.png" class="w3-image w3-third">
         <div class="w3-twothird"><h6>Leever Bontje Middig</h6>Bòntje middig geörganiseerd door V.V. De Tuinhagedisse</br></br>Laes verder -></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</li>
<div id="2" class="w3-modal">
   <div class="w3-modal-content w3-text-black w3-animate-zoom">
      <header class="w3-container w3-text-white" style="background-color: #005415;">
         <span onclick="document.getElementById('2').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Sjloete">&times;</span>
         <h2>Leever Bòntje Middig</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Bòntje middig geörganiseerd door vv de Tuinhagedisse</p>
      Bòntje middig geörganiseerd door vv de Tuinhagedisse veur miense oet Leeve én omsjtreke!</br>
      Mit o.a. optraejes van Toeter Thijs en Pyure.</br>
      De middig begint om 14.00 oer (zaal aope vanaaf 13.30 oer).</br>
      <p>Ein kaertje kost €5,00, daoveur krieg geer entree & koffie mit vlaai.</p>

      <p>Sjpisjaal veur de miense die van boete Leeve komme, is dur GRATIS verveur geregeld. Opsjtapplaatse: de Donderie en 't Paradies.</p>

      Kaertjes kinne besjteld waere via:</br>
      julia.orval@gmail.com óf jmhn@xs4all.nl</br>
      Gaef naam, adres, tillefoonnummer en 't aantal luuj door véúr 27 fibberwarie. VOL=VOL</br>

      Wilt geer meer informatie hubbe? Gebroek dan baovesjtaonde mailadressen of bel nao 06-16353489.
   </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM nuujts";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<li onclick='document.getElementById(".$row['id'].").style.display'block'' class='w3-border'>";
            echo "<a href='#'>";
               echo "<div class='w3-row'>";
                  echo $row['aafbeelding'];
                  echo "<div class='w3-twothird'><h6>".$row["titel"]."</h6>".$row["subtitel"]."</br></br>Laes verder -></div>";
               echo "</div>";
            echo "</a>";
         echo "</li>";
         echo "<div id='".$row["id"]."' class='w3-modal'>";
            echo "<div class='w3-modal-content w3-text-black w3-animate-zoom'>";
               echo "<header class='w3-container w3-text-white' style='background-color: #005415'>";
                  echo "<span onclick='document.getElementById(".$row['id'].").style.display='none'' class='w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright' title='Sjloete'>&times;</span>";
                  echo "<h2>".$row["titel"]."</h2>";
               echo "</header>";
               echo "<p>".$row["subtitel"]."</p>";
               echo $row["inhoud"];
            echo "</div>";
         echo "</div>";
      }
   }
?>
```

nothing happens but the modal should open. i believe the issues lays in the quotes but i can't wrap my head around the right quote usage

Comment: This is just wrong on a few levels `onclick='document.getElementById(".$row['id'].").style.display'block''`

Comment: You might want to look into what MVC is. Or at least look into heredoc syntax for PHP. As for the JS, just use a framework like jQuery and get the JS out of your markup. This code would be a real nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always simplify your PHP and not embed javascript but instead rely on javascript outside of PHP.

First, instead of onclick, output the id into a data attribute of `id` and add an additional class. Then use javascript to add click event handlers.

```
echo "<li data-id='{$row['id']}' class='show-modal w3-border'>";

echo "<span data-id='{$row['id']}' class='hide-modal w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright' title='Sjloete'>&times;</span>";


var objs = document.getElementsByClassName('show-modal');

for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    objs[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
       document.getElementById(this.dataset.id).style.display = 'block';
     })
  })(i);
}

var objs = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-modal');

for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    objs[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
       document.getElementById(this.dataset.id).style.display = 'none';
     })
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work.. i've got absolutly no knowledge about javascript so i'm really sorry. i've pasted var objs = document... until your last line at the bottom of my html in a <script> and edited the two php lines but the modals aren't opening

Comment: @Mark can you post the HTML output to your question and not the PHP pre-processed version?

Comment: edited my post everything should be clear right now

Comment: @Mark I apologize, I had a typo in my code. I just tested it and verified it does work.